# How do I use e.getValueIsAdjusting with a listener on both the rows and columns of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have a JTable which is representing a board in a game, and I need to be able to detect changes in the both the column and row.

```
tb = new JTable(board);
tb.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
tb.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(this);
```

But this means that when a row and a column is changed, the valueChanged method gets called twice, meaning my if statement

```
if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
```

is satisfied twice, which results in multiple checkers being put on the board.

I want to end up with just two coordinates of the cell which is now selected.
I understand this might be slightly poorly worded, but its the best description of the problem I can give.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `changeSelection(...)` method of JTable. This method is called every time the cell selection changes:

```
final JTable table1 = new JTable(5,5)
{
    @Override
    public void changeSelection(
        int row, int column, boolean toggle, boolean extend)
    {
        super.changeSelection(row, column, toggle, extend);

        System.out.println(row + " : " + column);
    }
};
```

> is satisfied twice, which results in multiple checkers being put on the board.

Check if a checker is already on the board at that point first before adding it.